# Where should "well" be located?

Tags: adverb-placement

Where should "well" go in this sentence to be idiomatic?

> Engineers do not evaluate **well** problems.

> Engineers do not evaluate problems **well**.

> Elsewhere?

Comment: *I speak **good** English* - uses ***good*** to adjectivally modify ***English***. Changing the sequence to *I speak English **good*** is dialectal / substandard use of ***good*** as an adverb modifying ***speak** [English]*. The correct adverbial form is *I speak English **well***. Note that *I speak **well** English* is completely unacceptable, so there's no point in asking whether ***well*** is an adjective or an adverb in that position.

Comment: The first one is definitely wrong - it sounds as though _well_ describes _problems_ (as opposed to sick ones, which is obviously nonsense).

Comment: Your first example *can* be grammatically correct English, but not in the way you mean. **Well** can also be a noun, a hole in the ground for water, oil or gas. Whilst the petroleum industry employs engineers who evaluate "well problems", there will be many more in other industries that do not evaluate well problems. And well is also the opposite of sick, so there a some engineers who only evaluate sick problems, whatever they are!

Comment: @KateBunting - When you find mud in the drinking water, you have *well problems.*

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther: Sick comment! :)

Answer (score 2):

*I speak **good** English* uses ***good*** to adjectivally modify ***English***.

Changing the sequence to *I speak English **good*** is dialectal / substandard use of ***good*** as an adverb modifying ***speak** [English]*.

The correct adverbial form is *I speak English **well***.

*I speak **well** English* is completely unacceptable<sup>1</sup>, so there's no point in asking whether well is an adjective or an adverb in that position.

---

<sup>1</sup> Unacceptable unless we imagine ridiculously contrived contexts where a ***well*** accesses underground water, or the word is being used as an antonym of ***ill, sick***.

Answer (score -1):

At the end mostly. Anywhere else and it's open to misinterpretations.

"Last year we dug a well. It's dried out now. I've asked a hydraulic engineer to come around to evaluate my well problems." :o)

Even if the object phrase modified by 'well' is very long.

"She makes that cake of hers with the ground almonds instead of flour very well."

Of course you could break it up a bit: "She makes that cake of hers very well; you know the one; she uses ground almonds in it instead of flour."

Comment: -1 for (mischievously?) including a completely unrelated use of the noun ***well*** in your examples. Non-native speakers don't need that pointless distraction.

Comment: Sorry, but that's ridiculous FumbleFingers! It's clearly intended as a moderately amusing example of how word order can cause mix-ups.  In fact I'm a little taken aback. I'll add a smiley to clarify that I'm making a joke.

Comment: That's fine, now. It's just that this business of multiple occurrences of "the same" word with multiple meanings and/or "parts of speech" has come up several times lately. Native speakers don't usually have any problems with it, but nns can find it difficult. Obviously the OP here *wasn't* thinking about wells for water (or well as opposed to sick, as per Kate's comment), so it's not really necessary to bring those alternatives up at all. But so long as you advertise the fact of something being effectively "whimsical", I would think that should be enough to guide an nns through.

Comment: (I'm sure many native Anglophones would chuckle at your "sly" introduction of the qualifier ***hydraulic*** to OP's ***engineers***. But lots of nns might miss that entirely unless they took the time and trouble to look up the word ***hydraulic***! :)

Comment: There was nothing sly about my use of "hydraulic". I promise! I just meant a water engineer! Really.

Comment: Well (pun intended! :), I'm sure you can see what I mean. We know perfectly well (good grief! ;) what ***hydraulic*** means, so it works fine for us. But that won't necessarily be the case for the OP or future nns visitors here.

Comment: Now I'm just waiting for someone to take issue with my comment *Note that **I speak well English** is completely unacceptable* under the question. In principle, that might well be acceptable if what I meant was *I speak the kind of "domain-specific" English jargon that hydraulic engineers use*.

Comment: That reminds me of the joke about the central European businessman: "I speeke very sirty two languiches, from vhich Enelisch is ze best!"  Hehe

Comment: I fail to see how all this brouhaha helps OPs in general. Why not just give the simplest answer and be done with it. Why get into all the weeds before reaching the lake?